# How to Get Sum of all Volume in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get sum of all volumes but i don't know on how to get sum of gallon/s to liter/s or milliliter/s.

I use this SQL query:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(SUM(Raw_Quantity * 
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name= 'mL/s'     THEN 1
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'liter/s'  THEN 1000
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'gallon/s' THEN 3.785
        END)) / 1000, ' liter/s') 
      WHEN TRIM(SUM(Raw_Quantity * 
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name= 'mL/s'     THEN 1
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'liter/s'  THEN 1000
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'gallon/s' THEN 3.785
        END)) + 0 >= 1 
      THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUM(Raw_Quantity * 
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name= 'mL/s'     THEN 1
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'liter/s'  THEN 1000
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'gallon/s' THEN 3.785
        END)) / 1, ' mL/s')
      WHEN TRIM(SUM(Raw_Quantity *
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name= 'mL/s'     THEN 1
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'liter/s'  THEN 1000
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'gallon/s' THEN 3.785
        END)) + 0 >= 3.785
      THEN CONCAT(TRIM(SUM(Raw_Quantity *
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name= 'mL/s'     THEN 1
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'liter/s'  THEN 1000
             WHEN Unit_Name= 'gallon/s' THEN 3.785
        END)) / 3.785, ' gallon/s')
      END) AS 'QUANTITY',
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE WHEN Unit_Name = 'liter/s' AND Raw_Expiration_Date.Raw_Quantity < 1     THEN 'mL/s'
             WHEN Unit_Name = 'gallon/s' AND  Raw_Expiration_Date.Raw_Quantity < 1     THEN 'liter/s'
             WHEN Unit_Name = 'liter/s' AND  Raw_Expiration_Date.Raw_Quantity > 3.785 THEN 'gallon/s'
             ELSE Unit_Name
        END) SEPARATOR '') AS 'Raw_Expiration_Date'
      FROM Raw_Expiration_Date
INNER JOIN Raw_Material_Table ON Raw_Expiration_Date.Raw_ID = Raw_Material_Table.Raw_ID
INNER JOIN unit_table ON unit_table.Unit_ID = raw_expiration_date.Unit_ID
  GROUP BY Raw_Material_Table.Raw_ID
  ORDER BY Raw_Name ASC;
```

This is my example data:

```
Raw_Quantity  Unit_Name
500           mL/s
3             liter/s 
6             liter/s
20.780        gallon/s
```

However, the result is incorrect:

> 9.5786523 liter/s

I think my mistake is on how to calculate gallon/s.  What am I doing wrong in these calculations?

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting the query.

Comment: 22.3652048 is the correct answer or higher. at my formula on conversion 1000 ml = 1 liter and 3.785 liter = 1 gallon

Comment: without reading your sql  - who would - it looks like you're putting too much calculation task into mysql. That long sql (with at least twice a concat) _cant_ be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are indeed 3.785 litres to a gallon, then the problem is that your gallon multiplier is 3.785, but it should be 3785.0